# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?. No entiendo si el `int edad` me esta fallando. Por favor guiarme, que puedo hacer ante este problema:

```
private void BTguardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String Carnét = TXTcarnet.getText();
        String Nombre = TXTnombre.getText();
        String Apellido = TXTape.getText();
        int Edad = Integer.parseInt(TXTedad.getText());
        String Email = TXTeamil.getText();
        int Telefono = Integer.parseInt(TXTtel.getText());
        String Sexo;
        if (clmas.isSelected()== true){
            Sexo = "M";
        }else if (clfe.isSelected() == true){
            Sexo = "F";
        }else{
            Sexo = "N/A";
        }`

        try {
            Connection con = conexion.getConexion();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Alumnos(Carnét,Nombre,Apellido,Edad,Email,Telefono,Sexo,Activo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            ps.setString(1,Carnét);
            ps.setString(2,Nombre);
            ps.setString(3,Apellido);
            ps.setInt(4,Edad);
            ps.setString(5,Email);
            ps.setInt(6,Telefono);
            ps.setString(7,Sexo);
            ps.setInt(8,1);
            ps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "REGISTRO GUARDADO");

        }catch(SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.toString());

        }

    }
```

Éste es el error que obtengo:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at sistema.interfaz.app.BTguardarActionPerformed(app.java:252)
    at sistema.interfaz.app.access$000(app.java:17)
    6.at sistema.interfaz.app$1.actionPerformed(app.java:71)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: En al menos una de las dos el getText() esta devolviendo una cadena vacia "", por lo que falla al intentar convertirla a numero.

Comment: y como puedo quitar cambiar o quitar la cadena vacia

Comment: me supongo que el query esta asociado a un botón ,antes de presionarlo debes asegurarte que los campos TxtEdad y TxtTel  contengan números no puedes hacer un cast de un campo vacío